# Figuring out conditional column transformation to make new column code with dplyr

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I'm working with a time series that has a couple of thousands of row, but here's a small sample of the two columns in question I want to talk about:

```
data <- data.frame(
        Precipitation = sample(c("0.12", "0.14", "0.08", "0.30", "0.10", "0.40", "1.6", "0", "0")),
        Character = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")))
```

Each value in the Precipitation column corresponds to the letter in the Character column (i.e. 0.12 -> A, 0.14 -> B, etc.).

Each of those letters represents a potential "change" that needs to be done to the values in the Precipitation column, which is:

- Precipitation values with letter A are fine as is
- Precipitation values with letter B need to be divided by 2
- Precipitation values with letter C need to be divided by 3
- Precipitation values with letter D need to be divided by 4
- Precipitation values with letter E need to be divided by 2
- Precipitation values with letter F need to be divided by 4
- Precipitation values with letter G need to be divided by 4
- Precipitation values with letter H are fine as is
- Precipitation valued with letter I are fine as is

Now, I want to make a new column using dplyr to do the divisions noted by the Character column onto the Precipitation column while also bringing over the corresponding A, H, and I rows that do not require any changes. What would the code look like to do this?

Thank you for your help! It is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? You may want to look at `case_when` in `dplyr`

Comment: @CalumYou I don't know how to approach this code-wise, so I'm looking for someone to help me with an example. :)

Comment: see case_when (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? It uses `case_when` in `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(
  Precipitation = sample(c(0.12, 0.14, 0.08, 0.30, 0.10, 0.40, 1.6, 0, 0)), 
  Character = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")))
```

I assume that your precipitation numbers were meant to me numbers and not characters or factors, so no quotation marks.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(new = case_when(Character == "B" ~ Precipitation/2,
                         Character == "C" ~ Precipitation/3,
                         Character == "D" ~ Precipitation/4,
                         Character == "E" ~ Precipitation/2,
                         Character == "F" ~ Precipitation/4,
                         Character == "G" ~ Precipitation/4,
                         TRUE ~ Precipitation))
```

Anything that is not "B" to "G" is represented by `TRUE` and is the original value (Precipitation).

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Precipitation Character   new
          <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1          0.12 F         0.03 
2          0.4  H         0.4  
3          0.3  B         0.15 
4          0.08 E         0.04 
5          0    I         0    
6          0.14 D         0.035
7          1.6  G         0.4  
8          0    C         0    
9          0.1  A         0.1
```